# Custom UICollectionViewLayout and floating supplementary header views crash

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a `UICollectionView` which represents a grid and I would like to create a ruler (floating header view) at the top edge which floats along in the y-axis. 
So, much like in `UITableView`s, this view should basically just scroll with the content at the top of the screen. I hope that description makes it clear enough. So much for theory, let's get to the practical part!

Here is what I am working with now:

- I registered the class `GridRulerView` which is a subclass of
  `UICollectionReusableView` with the collection view.
- I return the correct Size for the supplementary view for the right kind and CGSizeZero where there is no header.
- I implemented `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind::`

  ```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
  {
      var reusableHeaderView : UICollectionReusableView!
      if kind == GridRulerView.Kind{
          reusableHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(GridRulerView.Kind, withReuseIdentifier: GridRulerView.Kind, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView

      }
      return reusableHeaderView
  }
  ```

I have a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` with the following 
`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` method:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {

        var attribs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for (indexPath, attrs) in self.attributes{
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, attrs.frame) {
                attribs.append(attrs)
            }
        }

        var headerAttributes = GridViewRulerAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: GridRulerView.Kind, withIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0))
        headerAttributes.zIndex = 500
        headerAttributes.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.collectionView!.contentOffset.y, self.preCalculatedContentSize.width, 80)
        attribs.append(headerAttributes)

        return attribs

}
```

When I start the app, everything looks great, exactly how I want it.
BUT as soon as I scroll the collectionView beyond it's bounds (collectionView's contentOffset = (-0.5,-0.5) <- any negative values for example) I get a crash:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.25/UICollectionViewData.m:426

The interesting thing is that if I set the header view attribute's frame's y property to 0 instead of the variable contentOffset.y (which becomes negative), everything works fine.

Anybody any idea why this happens ?

### EDIT

Here is a more informative error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (GridRulerViewKind); frame = (0 0; 425.227 24); zIndex = 500;  to  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (GridRulerViewKind); frame = (0 -5; 425.227 24); zIndex = 500;  without invalidating the layout'

Comment: I believe that there is more information about this crash in few lines below `*** Assertion...`. Check them and they could give you a hint. For example there should be something like: `... *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ... reason: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Wow, actually disabled "All Exceptions" breakpoints and got a more informative error to work with:</strike>

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) changed from  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (GridRulerViewKind); frame = (0 0; 425.227 24); zIndex = 500;  to  index path: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}); element kind: (GridRulerViewKind); frame = (0 -5; 425.227 24); zIndex = 500;  without invalidating the layout'

Now, I still had no idea what to do, or where to

> "invalidate the layout"

Then while browsing similar questions, I came across a similar question here on SO where I stumbled upon this simple function:

```
override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool{
    return true
}
```

And sure enough, that seemed to work! No crash anymore!

### EDIT

Actually, this is causing the collection view layout to invalidate on every scroll, so this does not seem to be the solution I am looking for...

### Edit #2

After a bit of research, I don't think it is possible to create a supplementary view that changes by itself without invalidating the layout (which kind of seems perfectly logical - how would the layout know to just update the ruler view without explicitly saying so ?). And updating the layout on each scroll is just way too expensive.

So I figured I will just create a separate view which is entirely independent of the collection view and simply listening to the collection view's scroll delegate and adjusting its frame according to the scroll offset. I think this approach is much more efficient in terms of performance and is equally easy to implement.

Comment: you need to define which `representedElementCategory` you need to layout in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Just check representedElementKind

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributesForElementsInRect = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var newAttributesForElementsInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for attributes in attributesForElementsInRect! {

            if !(attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                || attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

                // cells will be customise here, but Header and Footer will have layout without changes.
            }

            newAttributesForElementsInRect.append(attributes)
        }

        return newAttributesForElementsInRect
    }
}


class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "HeaderCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")

        let footerNib = UINib.init(nibName: "FooterCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(footerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell")
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
            return headerView
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
            let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterCell", for: indexPath) as! FooterCell
            return footerView
        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 45)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 25)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why you are passing GridRulerView.Kind for ReuseIdentifier?

```
    reusableHeaderView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(GridRulerView.Kind, withReuseIdentifier: **GridRulerView.Kind**, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionReusableView
```

It should be as below.

> var supplementaryView =
>   collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind,
>   withReuseIdentifier:Identifiers.HeaderIdentifier.rawValue,
>   forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionReusableView

Comment: I added a static string property called "Kind" to the `GridViewRuler` class. Having both `kind` and `reuseIdentifier` as the same string should not cause this problem - correct me if I am wrong...